# Cannot get left earphone working

Tags: 12.04, sound, realtek

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.4LTS and my left earphone is not working. It is a brand new pair with nothing wrong with it so I know it's not an issue with the earphones. I have been googling for a good half hour if not more and trying various things but I have had no luck so far.

I ran `alsamixer` and I verified that "master volume" is NOT muted.

I was trying to install the Realtek driver as detailed in [this thread](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=107853#p514112) but I got the same error as detailed in that post linked to.

So what's going on here, there's no configure file in the stuff I downloaded from realtek? Why? :/

EDIT: Just stating for clarity, doing the sound test in `System > Sound` for the earphones does not give any sound out put when testing the left one, unsurprisingly.

EDIT #2: One of the courses of action I took in trying to resolve this was the original solution in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150887/sound-from-both-headphones-and-speakers/150959#150959), but it didn't fix it. As I mentioned above, running the install file fails with this error.

```
./install: 19: ./install: ./configure: not found
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target `install'. Stop.
./install: 23: ./install: ./snddevices: not found
```

So, taking a step back, let's forget about the possibility of something being broken in the PC for now. Now, does anyone know how I can resolve this error? Perhaps is there somewhere I can find the apparently missing makefile? My earlier google searches didn't give me anything.

Comment: did you try them somewhere else? I mean even new earphones can be broken.

Comment: Just tested them on my new Samsung smartphone that they came with, and yes, both of them work fine with it.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/316804/sound-only-works-from-left-speaker did you check this ?

Comment: Is it a laptop or a pc?

Comment: I know this might look weird but I had a similar issue where the problem was for some how; my headset plug wasn't compatible with the earphone socket in the labtop and both were working fine "individually" with others ( I mean other headset on the laptop and the headset on another device)......... so; try to test another headset on your laptop and see the result.

Comment: It is a PC. @Private Not sure if I had been on that page before you linked it but, it doesn't seem to be much help. If it really is some hardware problem (inside the PC) then that's pretty dumb...It's a work PC too so I probably can't do much about it.

Comment: With my last edit to the original post in mind, does anyone have something new to add..?