# PulseEffects sound only comes out of left speaker

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I recently switched to using Ubuntu 20.04 from Windows 10. After some searching, I found PulseEffects for audio enhancements. However when I use PulseEffects, sound only comes out of my left speaker. I already checked my sound settings and the balance settings are fine.

If I turn PulseEffects off, both speakers work, so I know it isn't hardware.

Suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Damn. Managed to fix it? I have the exact same problem -_-

Comment: Just stumbled upon this issue also. @Xammed Kain did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316804/sound-only-works-from-left-speaker).

My issue was with *pulseEffects* set for the left side only in sound settings, just had to move it to center and it works fine now:

[image: settings]