# How to configure mono instead of stereo sound?

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, hardware, headset

Using a `USB` headset with a single speaker, shown here as `Y-247A`:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 2a7a:6a18 CASUE CASUE USB Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 045e:0040 Microsoft Corp. Wheel Mouse Optical
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0d8c:0014 C-Media Electronics, Inc. Audio Adapter (Unitek Y-247A)
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ uname -a
Linux mordor 5.11.0-34-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 26 19:22:09 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

Regardless of [which](https://askubuntu.com/q/316804/847449) output is selected:

[image: left speaker]

only one "speaker" from the above `GUI` will produce sounds from the headset.  The headset has one speaker for one ear, the other ear has no speaker.

While the the output of `pactl list` is a bit extensive, perhaps this would be how to configure for a single speaker.

How do I make the sound "mono"?

*Note:  The [sound](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sound-usespeakers.html.en) works fine at least for `Microsoft Teams` and `Text Now` so this is primarily just wanting to get that test to work for both speakers.*

Comment: You should be able to flip the balance completely to the left or right depending on what speaker it is.

Comment: Yes, that's the question I meant to ask!  I'll look into alsa mixer or other options.  Thanks @Terrance for that.